# Disable Lock Screen on Resume

Tags: suspend, screen, hibernate, lock-screen, lock

I am using Ubuntu 19.04 and am attempting to disable the lock screen from appearing on resume completely.

I have disabled the Screen Lock in Settings, installed the "Disable Screen Shield" extension and carried out the following command:

```
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.lockdown disable-lock-screen 'true'
```

Whenever my computer suspends after closing the laptop lid or by manually suspending it, the lock screen no longer appears on resume. However, if my computer suspends because of inactivity (15 minutes) the lock screen still appears on resume. Is anyone able to advise?

Many thanks.

Comment: Don't know the answer, but the question was useful. :D

Answer (score 0):

Running either or both of these commands may help:

```bsh
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.screensaver ubuntu-lock-on-suspend 'false'
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.screensaver lock-enabled 'false'
```

Comment: What would the GUI equivalent of these two commands be? These didn't help me.